# How to fix 419 page expire error when submitting a form in laravel PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I am developing a laravel project that supports progressive web app and when I submit a form for login, it works fine but whenever I submit a form from logging out or submitting from any other form, I am getting 419 expire page error.

This is my service worker code:

```
const staticCache = 'my-pwa-static-v2';
const dynamicCache = 'my-pwa-dynamic-v2';

const assets = [
  '/login',
  'fallback.blade.php',
  'css/auth/users.css',
  'css/resident/resident-layout.css',
  'images/welcome-bg.png',
  'js/resident/resident-sidebar.js',
  'js/app.js',
];


// install service worker
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCache).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(assets);
    })
  );
});

// activates service worker
self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cache => {
          if(cache !== staticCache && cache !== dynamicCache){
            console.log('Cleaning old caches.');
            return caches.delete(cache);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(response => {
      return caches.open(dynamicCache).then(cache => {
        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        return response;
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return caches.match('fallback.blade.php');
      });
    })
  );
});
```